# How to enable a copy option on screen long tap in Android?

Tags: android

I am developing an `Android` app and I need to enable a copy option by long tap on screen.

How to do that?

Comment: Can you be a little lit more specific...? What is the "option" you are talking about ? Some code too ?

Comment: Basically it is clipboard option

Answer (score 0):

You can use Clipboard functionality

```
private ClipboardManager myClipboard;
myClipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
```

To Copy Data

```
String text = copytext.getText().toString();
myClip = ClipData.newPlainText("text", text);
myClipboard.setPrimaryClip(myClip);
```

To Paste Data

```
ClipData cp = myClipboard.getPrimaryClip();
ClipData.Item item = cp.getItemAt(0);
String text = item.getText().toString();
```